# Wrong order for writing to a file with print function() and subprocess.call(... stdout=f)

Tags: python, file, printing

I want to write to a file with both the functions `print(.., f)` and `subprocess.run(.., stdout=f)`, but although I call print first, the written data of the `subprocess.run` always come first in the text file.

Here is my code:

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
...
print(abc, file=f)
for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
     print(letter, file=f)
     subprocess.run("...", encoding = 'utf8', stdout=f)
f.close()
```

Although I use the print function first to write to the file, the written data of the print function is at the bottom of the text file.
What can I do to preserve the right order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python buffers output to files, but the subprocess is writing directly to the file, not the Python buffer. Flush the buffer first.

```
for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    print(letter, file=f)
    f.flush()
    subprocess.run("...", encoding = 'utf8', stdout=f)
```

Comment: Ok thanks that helped :)
Do you know if thats also the best solution in terms of runtime?
Because i want to iterate a really really big list.

Comment: Other question: Do you know how i can check if my Stdout ist empty/the subprocess.run has no return value, for an if query?

Comment: Simplest way would be to use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, read the output yourself, and then write it to the file.

Comment: And how would i use it for an if query? `If subprocess.PIPE:... else:...` ?

Comment: if subprocess.PIPE:
                                f.write(subprocess.PIPE)
                        else:
                                f.write('N/A')

Doesnt work..

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is `subprocess.check_output()`.

Comment: Maybe instead of guessing you should read the `subprocess` documentation. It explains how to read the output when you use `stdout=PIPE`.

Comment: I already checked the documentation, but `subprocess.check_output()` only gives me the return code of the ´subprocess.run´ function call. That is in both of my cases 0 though, because even if i get no output, the call is sucessfull, if you know what i mean.

Comment: The documentation says **Run command with arguments and return its output.** I don't know why it's only giving you the return code.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Yeah, but i dont want to call the function twice, then i rather let it empty, because i need low runtime.
I just need a 'if' check for the content of the stdout pipe of the `subprocess.run` call.

Comment: You don't call it twice. You call it once, read the output into a variable. Then write the variable to the file.

Comment: So when my stdout is empty, subprocess.check_output() is empty?
How can i syntactically check on that?
With subprocess.check_output(stdout=f) i still get the output written to File f?

Comment: `result = subprocess.check_output(...) if result: ...`